Patch images to an existing image column in a collection in PowerApps
So I am pulling data into a collection from a SQL server. I then add and rename columns to a new collection to match my sharepoint datasource.
ClearCollect(
AddColumnCollection,
AddColumns(
ColFilteredAssetids,
SafetyConcernPic2, LookUp(FieldAuditLocationSharepoint, Text(AssetID) = Text(assetid), SafetyConcernPic2),
SafetyConcernPicture, LookUp(FieldAuditLocationSharepoint, Text(AssetID) = Text(assetid), SafetyConcernPicture),
SafetyConcerns, LookUp(FieldAuditLocationSharepoint, Text(AssetID) = Text(assetid), SafetyConcerns),
LiftType, LookUp(FieldAuditLocationSharepoint, Text(AssetID) = Text(assetid), LiftType),
WellInformationComments, LookUp(FieldAuditLocationSharepoint, Text(AssetID) = Text(assetid), WellInformationComments),
AuditComplete, LookUp(FieldAuditLocationSharepoint, Text(AssetID) = Text(assetid), AuditComplete),
SafetyConcernPic1Comments, LookUp(FieldAuditLocationSharepoint, Text(AssetID) = Text(assetid), SafetyConcernPic1Comments),
SafetyConcernPic2Comments, LookUp(FieldAuditLocationSharepoint, Text(AssetID) = Text(assetid), SafetyConcernPic2Comments),
AdditionalPic1, LookUp(FieldAuditLocationSharepoint, Text(AssetID) = Text(assetid), AdditionalPic1),
AdditionalPic1Comments, LookUp(FieldAuditLocationSharepoint, Text(AssetID) = Text(assetid), AdditionalPic1Comments),
AdditionalPic2, LookUp(FieldAuditLocationSharepoint, Text(AssetID) = Text(assetid), AdditionalPic2),
AdditionalPic2Comments, LookUp(FieldAuditLocationSharepoint, Text(AssetID) = Text(assetid), AdditionalPic2Comments),
AdditionalPic3, LookUp(FieldAuditLocationSharepoint, Text(AssetID) = Text(assetid), AdditionalPic3),
AdditionalPic3Comments, LookUp(FieldAuditLocationSharepoint, Text(AssetID) = Text(assetid), AdditionalPic3Comments),
AdditionalPic4, LookUp(FieldAuditLocationSharepoint, Text(AssetID) = Text(assetid), AdditionalPic4),
AdditionalPic4Comments, LookUp(FieldAuditLocationSharepoint, Text(AssetID) = Text(assetid), AdditionalPic4Comments),
AdditionalPic5, LookUp(FieldAuditLocationSharepoint, Text(AssetID) = Text(assetid), AdditionalPic5),
AdditionalPic5Comments, LookUp(FieldAuditLocationSharepoint, Text(AssetID) = Text(assetid), AdditionalPic5Comments),
AdditionalPic6, LookUp(FieldAuditLocationSharepoint, Text(AssetID) = Text(assetid), AdditionalPic6),
AdditionalPic6Comments, LookUp(FieldAuditLocationSharepoint, Text(AssetID) = Text(assetid), AdditionalPic6Comments),
AdditionalPic7, LookUp(FieldAuditLocationSharepoint, Text(AssetID) = Text(assetid), AdditionalPic7),
AdditionalPic7Comments, LookUp(FieldAuditLocationSharepoint, Text(AssetID) = Text(assetid), AdditionalPic7Comments),
AdditionalPic8, LookUp(FieldAuditLocationSharepoint, Text(AssetID) = Text(assetid), AdditionalPic8),
AdditionalPic8Comments, LookUp(FieldAuditLocationSharepoint, Text(AssetID) = Text(assetid), AdditionalPic8Comments),
ID, LookUp(FieldAuditLocationSharepoint, Text(AssetID) = Text(assetid), ID)
)
);
ClearCollect(
MergedCollection,
RenameColumns(AddColumnCollection,
custlegalname, Customer,
assetname, AssetName,
assetid, AssetID,
siteid, SiteID,
sitename, Sitename,
district, District,
route, Route,
latitude, Latitude,
longitude, Longitude
));
I then put that MergedCollection into a gallery as items. I want to then edit those so when I select an item it populates a new EditForm with the records data and then I add data I want for that record to then patch a collection.
If(Connection.Connected,
SubmitForm(EditForm1_21);,
ClearCollect(FieldAuditLocationSharepoint, FieldAuditLocationData);
Collect(FieldAuditLocationEntries, EditForm1_21.Updates);
SaveData(FieldAuditLocationEntries, "OfflineFieldAuditLocationEntries");
);
Set(
varExistingSafetyConcernPicture,
LookUp(MergedCollection, AssetID = varSelectedAsset.AssetID).SafetyConcernPicture
);
Patch(MergedCollection, LookUp(MergedCollection, AssetID = varSelectedAsset.AssetID),
{
Customer: Customer_DataCard3.Update,
AssetName: AssetName_DataCard1.Update,
District: District_DataCard3.Update,
Sitename: Sitename_DataCard2.Update,
AssetID: Value(AssetID_DataCard1.Update),
SiteID: Value(SiteID_DataCard2.Update),
Route: Route_DataCard1.Update,
Latitude: Latitude_DataCard2.Update,
Longitude: Longitude_DataCard2.Update,
SafetyConcernPic2: SafetyConcernPic2_DataCard1.Update,
SafetyConcernPicture: SafetyConcernPicture_DataCard1.Update,
SafetyConcerns: SafetyConcerns_DataCard1.Update,
LiftType: LiftType_DataCard1.Update,
WellInformationComments: WellInformationComments_DataCard1.Update,
AuditComplete: AuditComplete_DataCard1.Update,
SafetyConcernPic1Comments: SafetyConcernPic1Comments_DataCard1.Update,
SafetyConcernPic2Comments: SafetyConcernPic2Comments_DataCard1.Update,
AdditionalPic1: AdditionalPic1_DataCard1.Update,
AdditionalPic1Comments: AdditionalPic1Comments_DataCard1.Update,
AdditionalPic2: AdditionalPic2_DataCard1.Update,
AdditionalPic2Comments: AdditionalPic2Comments_DataCard1.Update,
AdditionalPic3: AdditionalPic3_DataCard1.Update,
AdditionalPic3Comments: AdditionalPic3Comments_DataCard1.Update,
AdditionalPic4: AdditionalPic4_DataCard1.Update,
AdditionalPic4Comments: AdditionalPic4Comments_DataCard1.Update,
AdditionalPic5: AdditionalPic5_DataCard1.Update,
AdditionalPic5Comments: AdditionalPic5Comments_DataCard1.Update,
AdditionalPic6: AdditionalPic6_DataCard1.Update,
AdditionalPic6Comments: AdditionalPic6Comments_DataCard1.Update,
AdditionalPic7: AdditionalPic7_DataCard1.Update,
AdditionalPic7Comments: AdditionalPic7Comments_DataCard1.Update,
AdditionalPic8: AdditionalPic8_DataCard1.Update,
AdditionalPic8Comments: AdditionalPic8Comments_DataCard1.Update,
ID: Value(ID_DataCard2.Default)
}
);
So far it works fine until the patch. When I patch the image that is in the existing record disappears. It seems like the patch function isn't keeping or patch the image properly to the collection. I want to be able to update the collection whether I am online or offline.
Any ideas would be great!
Within the patch I have tried putting in the Image2.Image, but it says expecting a record
Patch(MergedCollection, LookUp(MergedCollection, AssetID = varSelectedAsset.AssetID),
{
    SafetyConcernPicture: Image2.Image,}


Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
